# How to print value in perl

Tags: perl

I am expecting below information to be printed in cmd prompt
Expected value :

```
(set "a=10")
```

cmd :

```
@value = "(set " . \"a=10)\"";
print @value;
```

o/p :

```
(set SCALAR(0x43f8f0)& echo %a%
```

Answer (score 2):

Backslash on the wrong place,

```
@value = "(set " . "\"a=10\")";
```

output

```
(set "a=10")
```

or simply

```
my $value = q{(set "a=10")};
```

More quoting options in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

Answer (score 1):

```
@value = "(set " . \"a=10)\"";
               ^   ^
               |   |
       String end. |
                   |
            Outside quotes,
         this means reference.
```

Why do you need an array anyway?

```
$value = '(set "a=10")';
print $value;
```